# Error when executing Maven Command in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I and running Jenkins in a Docker Container on my mac (locally) as per these instructions -

https://hackmamba.io/blog/2022/04/running-docker-in-a-jenkins-container/

I have installed my jdk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeXmH.png)

and set my Java Home here -

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXZB9.png)

This is my simple pipelime

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    tools {
        // Install the Maven version configured as "M3" and add it to the path.
        maven '3.8.7'
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo ls '
                sh 'echo $JAVA_HOME'
               
                // Run Maven on a Unix agent.
                sh 'mvn --version'

         
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Every time I get this -

The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
this environment variable is needed to run this program.

I have no idea of how to find the path Jenkins installed the jdk too when it automatically installed it.

Please help

I've tried changing the path for JAVA_HOME - but I don't know what it would be in this environemnt

Comment: OK I have now figured out the JAVA_HOME path - but I now get "
qemu-aarch64: Could not open '/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1': No such file or directory". when I run "+ mvn --version"

Comment: If you have maven installed on your Jenkins host, try removing the `tools` section to see if the problem continues.

Answer (score 0):

Which docker image this container made of? if it's official jeknins docker image - java comes installed already, and you do not need to install it. (as long as you are not adding nodes/agents).

However, if you need to install it, the installation should be in a local path in the container. you can give a specific location for the installation:

```
~/installed-here/
```

then the path should be ~/installed-here/jdk....
and JAVA_HOME should point to this path (a local linux/win path that in the container)